# dynamic type tests not working as expected

Tags: flowtype

This is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

I have a map container class where an internal `Map` is created on demand with the first `set` method that gets called:

```
// @flow
'use strict';

class MapContainer {

    map: ?Map<any, any>;

    constructor() {
        this.map=null;
    }

    set(key: any, value: any): ?any {
        if (this.map===null) {
            this.map = new Map();
        }
        let prevValue: ?any;
        if (this.map!=null) { // first check
            prevValue = this.map.get(key);
        }
        if (this.map!=null) { // second check
            this.map.set(key, value);
        }
        return prevValue;
    }
}    
exports.MapContainer = MapContainer;
```

The above code passes `npm run flow` with no warnings.

However if I merge the two `if (this.map!=null)` checks into one:

```
// @flow
'use strict';

class MapContainer {

    map: ?Map<any, any>;

    constructor() {
        this.map=null;
    }

    set(key: any, value: any): ?any {
        if (this.map===null) {
            this.map = new Map();
        }
        let prevValue: ?any;
        if (this.map!=null) { // merged check
            prevValue = this.map.get(key);
            this.map.set(key, value);
        }
        return prevValue;
    }
}    
exports.MapContainer = MapContainer;
```

… then running flow fails with the following message:

```
es6/map-container.js:19
 19:                 this.map.set(key, value);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `set`. Method cannot be called on possibly null value
 19:                 this.map.set(key, value);
                 ^^^^^^^^ null

es6/map-container.js:19
 19:                 this.map.set(key, value);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `set`. Method cannot be called on possibly undefined value
 19:                 this.map.set(key, value);
                 ^^^^^^^^ undefined
```

… which makes no sense at all as the access on line 19:

`this.map.set(key,value)`

… is still covered by the check:

`if (this.map!=null)`

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that call to `get` method can invalidates refinement. What if `get` sets `this.map` to `null`? Flow has no way of knowing, so it assumes the worst. Here is what you can do:

```
class MapContainer {

    map: ?Map<any, any>;

    constructor() {
        this.map=null;
    }

    set(key: any, value: any): ?any {     
        if (!this.map) {
            this.map = new Map();
        }

        const map = this.map;

        let prevValue: ?any;
        if (this.map!=null) {
            prevValue = map.get(key);
            map.set(key, value);
        }
        return prevValue;
    }
}
```