# weird `Method cannot be called on possibly null / undefined value`

Tags: flowtype

The following narrowed-down code:

// @flow
    'use strict';

```js
import assert from 'assert';

class Node<V, E> {
    value: V;
    children: ?Map<E, Node<V,E>>;

    constructor(value: V) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = null;
    }
}


function accessChildren(tree: Node<number, string>): void {

    if (tree.children!=null) {
        assert(true); // if you comment this line Flow is ok
        tree.children.forEach( (v,k)=>{});
    } else {
    }

}
```

… fails Flow type checking with the following message:

```js
$ npm run flow

> simple-babel-serverside-node-only-archetype@1.0.0 flow /home/blah/blah/blah
> flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2

es6/foo.js:21
21:             tree.children.forEach( (v,k)=>{});
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `forEach`. Method cannot be called on possibly null value
21:             tree.children.forEach( (v,k)=>{});
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null

es6/foo.js:21
21:             tree.children.forEach( (v,k)=>{});
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `forEach`. Method cannot be called on possibly undefined value
21:             tree.children.forEach( (v,k)=>{});
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined


Found 2 errors
```

If the line reading: `assert(true)` is commented out, flow is satisfied !

What gives?

**PS:** In case anyone wonders, my `.flowconfig`, `.babelrc` and `package.json` files are nondescript:

## .flowconfig

```js
$ cat .flowconfig
[options]
esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
```

## .babelrc

```js
$ cat .babelrc
{
"presets": ["es2015"],
"plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-flow-strip-types", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

## package.json

```js
$ cat package.json
{
"name": "simple-babel-serverside-node-only-archetype",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": [
"index.js"
],
"scripts": {
"build": "babel es6 --out-dir es5 --source-maps",
"build-watch": "babel es6 --out-dir es5 --source-maps --watch",
"start": "node es5/index.js",
"flow": "flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.6.5",
"babel-core": "^6.7.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.10.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.8.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
"flow-bin": "^0.27.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
"source-map-support": "^0.4.0"
}
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479426/dynamic-type-tests-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @vkurchatkin initially I thought as much but it's not. `assert(true)` has no way of modifying `tree.children` so Flow should have allowed that. This is different to the post you link to where a member method was called that had the potential to access `this`. Unless Flow considers that the function `assert` was perhaps created in a way that allowed it to capture a closure over the `tree` local variable, I dunno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case is described [here](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#caveats).

Flow cannot know, that `assert` doesn't change the `tree`.
Add the following lines to your code and run it – you will have runtime error, because assert function will set `tree.children` to `null` when called.

```javascript
const root = new Node(1);
const child = new Node(2);

root.children = new Map([['child', child]]);

assert = () => root.children = null;

accessChildren(root);
```

Yes, it is pretty weird code, but Flow doesn't know, you will not to write it.

Comment: thanks for the clear and concise answer. That actually makes loads of sense!

Answer (score 4):

Others have pointed to the right explanation. Fortunately this works:

```
// @flow
'use strict';

import assert from 'assert';

class Node<V, E> {
  value: V;
  children: ?Map<E, Node<V, E>>;

  constructor(value: V) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = null;
  }
}

function accessChildren(tree: Node<number, string>): void {
  const children = tree.children; // save possibly mutable reference to local
  if (children != null) {
    assert(true); // if you comment this line Flow is ok
    children.forEach((v, k) => {});
  } else {
  }
}
```

Also, in the future Flow will have read-only properties and by declaring `children` as a read-only property in the class, Flow should be able to preserve type check the original code.